# Checking out repository based on loaded SSH keys

Tags: git, version-control

I have setup my git server using Gitosis. I need to checkout the repository as different user on the same machine.

Suppose there are two machines:

1. Linux based server (on which the repo is held under user name "GIT"; another user "Dev1" is one of the developers)
2. Windows machine (user name "tech_geek")

How can I checkout the repo as "Dev1" to the Windows machine and also as "tech_geek"?
So there will be two repositories checked out on the windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

1) Clone Gitosis admin repo:

```
$ git clone git@SERVER:gitosis-admin.git
```

2) Add Dev1's and tech_geek's SSH public keys to `gitosis-admin/keydir` (rename each public key id_rsa.pub) as **dev1.pub** and **tech_geek.pub**. Add to file `gitosis-admin/gitosis.conf`

```
[group developers]
members = dev1 tech_geek
[group new_project]
writable = new_project
members = @developers
```

where ***new_project*** is repo name (without .git suffix)
3) Commit and push

```
$ cd gitosis-admin
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "New devs and repo for new_project"
$ git push
```

4) Try to clone repo (as user Dev1 or tech_geek) from Windows hosts

```
$ git clone git@SERVER:new_project.git
```

Comment: done till this but the thing is how to determine that i am cloning as dev1 or tech_geek???

Comment: by user's private key (id_rsa or id_dsa)

Comment: Take a look this chapter [Git server authentication using SSH public keys](http://progit.org/book/ch4-3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays use the environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND . (GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example" git clone example)

See:
https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

If you use one of the GUI tools it might be easier for you to choose the key.